# Does Cassandra 4.1.4 support Java17? Or only Cassandra 5.x

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

Just wondering if the current stable version Cassandra 4.1.4 support Java17?

I am currently using java11 works fine.

I try to change JAVA_HOME to openjdk@17 but get the JavaClassNotFound error when try to run it, also saw apache cassandra website says support java 17, so just wondering if it only support cassandra 5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Cassandra 4 will run on Java 8 and Java 11.

Cassandra 5 runs on Java 11 and Java 17.